# Configuration to optimize cassandra java/scala driver for intensive IO operations?

Tags: scala, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax-java-driver

I can't find any configuration for pooling option on cassandra (using Scala, but I can managed with Java examples). Has anyone ever done it before ?

**Edit** :  I'm using the j[ava driver with scala extra](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver-scala-extras). My goal is to optimise an intensive IO application (DB Read queries).

Comment: What client are you using?

Comment: The defaults are really good for most use cases. I wouldn't touch them unless theres a reason (ie busy pool exceptions).

Comment: what do you mean? pooling options of Java driver?

Comment: @DavidS. I added details about the driver.

Comment: @AlexOtt I am tuning every option to have a performance increase for IO apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tune as described in the [driver's documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/). Cassandra 2.0 uses protocol V2 that has limit on the amount of the in-flight requests, so you have only possibility to increase a number of connections opened from driver to Cassandra. By default, [for protocol V2 it has](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.6/manual/pooling/#pool-size) minimum 2 connections and maximum 2 connections.  You can increase it to 4 minimum and 10 maximum with following code:

```
PoolingOptions poolingOptions = new PoolingOptions();
poolingOptions
    .setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL,  4, 10)
    .setConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, 2, 4);
```

and options should be added when you create Cluster/Session objects:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
    .withContactPoints("127.0.0.1")
    .withPoolingOptions(poolingOptions)
    .build();
```

Comment: could you describe more the parameters used for the `setConnectionsPerHost` method please ?

Comment: firsr parameters defines for which distance the number will change (`LOCAL` is for local DC, `REMOTE` is for all other DCs), 1st number is min (core) number of connections, 2nd number is max number of open connections...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score -1):

Since you're in a JVM environment, you can just load the working Java configs via Scala.